# How do I add a function to a specific element type in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can do this

```
jQuery.fn.validate = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        validateOPtions1 : '',
        validateOPtions2 : ''
    };

    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
        // you validation code goes here
    });
};
```

but that will make validate() available for every element. I could do this to any element: $('some selector').validate().

Is there a way I can make this only available to, say, form elements? eg. $('.mySpecialFormClass').validate()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to have the function throw an exception if you **really** don't want it to work for anything but a `<form>` tag.

```
jQuery.fn.formsOnly = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    if (!$(this).is('form')) throw "Forms only!";
    // whatever
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple:

```
$('form').validate();
```

Selectors work a bit like this in jQuery (just as in CSS)

```
$('elementType.className')
```

See [this page](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more details on selectors.

Comment: I want to make it so that .validate() is unavailable to anything except elements of type 'form'. So, if I called, $('div').validate(), an 'undefined function' should would be thrown. For instance, .val() (I believe) only works with form element (input, select, textarea).

Comment: @Chad that's not the case - you can use `val()` with anything you want. It won't *work*, of course, but the framework doesn't make it impossible to even call it.

Comment: In that case, I agree with Pointy's answer.